# select and deselect object in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

i am making a game in which i am using is-clicked function when i click the object the letter written on it displayed now i want that when i clicked the same object again the word disappear... now how can i do that?

```
#pragma strict

static var nextPos = 200;
var word: String;
var sel: String;
var isClicked : boolean=false;
var xpos: float = 200;

function OnMouseDown()
{
    if (!isClicked) {
       isClicked = true;
       xpos = nextPos;
       nextPos += 8;

      } 
}
function OnGUI()
{  

   if (gameObject.name == "Sphere(Clone)" && isClicked )
   {
          GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos,260,400,100), "A");


   }

   else if (gameObject.name == "Sphere 1(Clone)" && isClicked )
   {
          GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos,260,400,100), "B");

   }  

   else if (gameObject.name == "Sphere 2(Clone)" && isClicked )
   {
          GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos,260,400,100), "C");

   }

   else if (gameObject.name == "Sphere 3(Clone)" && isClicked )
   {
          GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos,260,400,100), "D");
   }
}
```

Comment: where did you attached this script ? i.e to which GameObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write in OnMouseDown

```
else if(isClicked)
  {
  isClicked = false;
  // do your xpos stuff here
  }
```

Comment: I want that the letter written in the last only remove when i click not the letters behind it... for that what should i do